# matplotlib grouped bar color change

Tags: matplotlib, graph, data-visualization

I am trying to compare group A and group B using grouped bar, but group A must have the same colors and group B must have different colors and legends. I somehow created graph, but not sure how to change the color of each group B bar graphs..

```
import matplotlib 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np


labels = ['M1', 'A1', 'M2', 'A2', 'M3', 'A3', 'M4', 'A4', 'M5', 'A5'] 
A_group = [20, 34, 30, 35, 27, 17, 64, 23, 47, 52] 
B_group = [25, 32, 34, 20, 25, 76, 33, 54, 16, 21]

x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations 
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, A_group, width, label='A group') 
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, B_group, width, label='B group')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc. 

ax.set_ylabel('Accuracy') 
ax.set_title('Test') 
ax.set_xticks(x) 
ax.set_xticklabels(labels) 
ax.legend()

ax.bar_label(rects1, padding=3) 
ax.bar_label(rects2, padding=3) 
plt.xticks(rotation=30, ha='right') 
plt.ylim(0, 100) 

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Now my graph looks like this:

[image]

I want to make my graph like this. Below is an example using powerpoint.
[image]

Any helps will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what're the criteria for colring group B?

Comment: any colors are fine, if that's what you mean.. as long as they're different from group A. 2 grouped bars are one subcategory, so I need 1 color for group A and 5 colors for group B total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try drawing the bars in `B_group` one by one:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x-width/2, A_group, width=width,label='A Group')

cmap = plt.get_cmap('tab20')
ax.set_prop_cycle(color=[cmap(k) for k in x+1])
for i in x:
    ax.bar(i+width/2, B_group[i], width=width)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, but is there any way to reduce the number of colors? in B_group?

Comment: Yes, change to, e.g. `color=[cmap(k//2+1) for k in x]` in `ax.set_prop_cycle` would change the colors every two bars, similar to your expected output.